# Determine credit card type by number?

Tags: e-commerce, credit-card

Can credit card type be determined solely from the credit card number?

Is this recommended or should we always ask client for the type of credit card they're using?

I Googled about it and found this algorithm: http://cuinl.tripod.com/Tips/o-1.htm , is this reliable?

Comment: +1 -- always wondered how Paypal's slick card entry form works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you detect Credit card type based on number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, the site you mentioned is correct. Many sites, incl. Google Checkout I believe, rely on automatic detection of the card type. It's convenient, makes the UI less cluttered (one less input box) and saves time. Go ahead!

Comment: +1 Probably the only reason to provide a drop-down box for the card type is as a means of error checking.

Comment: a dropdown or list of icons is still useful - as it allows you to see what card types the company accepts before you enter it - for instance some may not take amex, diners, maestro etc.

Answer (score 21):

I have heard one good reason to make them pick (even though you can figure it out).  So that they know the list of credit cards you accept.

Comment: Additionally, it's just a good thing to be able to check against.

Comment: Interesting reason, but I don't agree with it. You can easily *show* the user what cards you accept with little icons or text without making them do any extra work.

Answer (score 11):

As a consumer, I hate choosing a card first. I want to just start typing the number.

This issue is discussed in Wroblewski's *[Web Form Design](http://www.rosenfeldmedia.com/books/webforms/)* on pages 153-154. It's in the section "Removing Questions" of the chapter "Unnecessary Inputs." The example given is Paypal, which highlights the type of card when you've typed in your number.

Comment: And what happens if they don't accept Amex (as often happens) ? Do you list the cards you don't accept ?

Comment: Paypal has graphic representations for all allowed card types shown but ghosted. When you type the number, the matching card brightens to full intensity.

Answer (score 7):

I am pretty certain that at least for MasterCard, Visa, Discover, and American Express that that is accurate.  I have never worked with any of the others.

This is pretty interesting to:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number

Comment: http://www.barclaycardbusiness.co.uk/docs/binranges.pdf has BIN ranges for cards, from a UK bank, so its going to be accurate.

Comment: Updated url for @gbjbaanb's comment: http://www.barclaycard.co.uk/business/documents/pdfs/bin_rules.pdf

Answer (score 5):

here is the script that i use that works with current card ranges. also does a validity check on the number.

```
/**
* checks a given string for a valid credit card
* @returns:
*   -1  invalid
*       1   mastercard
*       2   visa
*       3   amex
*       4   diners club
*       5   discover
*       6   enRoute
*       7   jcb
*/
function checkCC(val) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
        return (this.match("^" + str) == str)
    }

    Array.prototype.has=function(v,i){
        for (var j=0;j<this.length;j++){
            if (this[j]==v) return (!i ? true : j);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // get rid of all non-numbers (space etc)
    val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

    // now get digits
    var d = new Array();
    var a = 0;
    var len = 0;
    var cval = val;
    while (cval != 0) {
        d[a] = cval%10;
        cval -= d[a];
        cval /= 10;
        a++;
        len++;
    }

    if (len < 13)
        return -1;

    var cType = -1;

    // mastercard
    if (val.startsWith("5")) {
        if (len != 16)
            return -1;
        cType = 1;
    } else
    // visa
    if (val.startsWith("4")) {
        if (len != 16 && len != 13)
            return -1;
        cType = 2;
    } else
    // amex
    if (val.startsWith("34") || val.startsWith("37")) {
        if (len != 15)
            return -1;
        cType = 3;
    } else
    // diners
    if (val.startsWith("36") || val.startsWith("38") || val.startsWith("300") || val.startsWith("301") || val.startsWith("302") || val.startsWith("303") || val.startsWith("304") || val.startsWith("305")) {
        if (len != 14)
        return -1;
        cType = 4;
    } else
    // discover
    if (val.startsWith("6011")) {
        if (len != 15 && len != 16)
            return -1;
        cType = 5;
    } else
    // enRoute
    if (val.startsWith("2014") || val.startsWith("2149")) {
        if (len != 15 && len != 16)
            return -1;
        // any digit check
        return 6;
    } else
    // jcb
    if (val.startsWith("3")) {
        if (len != 16)
        return -1;
        cType = 7;
    } else
    // jcb
    if (val.startsWith("2131") || val.startsWith("1800")) {                                         

        if (len != 15)
        return -1;
        cType = 7;
    } else
    return - 1;
    // invalid cc company

    // lets do some calculation
    var sum = 0;
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < len; i += 2) {
        var s = d[i] * 2;
        sum += s % 10;
        sum += (s - s%10) /10;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
        sum += d[i];

    // musst be %10
    if (sum%10 != 0)
        return - 1;

    return cType;
}
```

Comment: was my bad... i just remembered using that function and having to update some exception because of customer complains (some valid cc# didnt come through) - but that was actually due to the length check

Comment: Most Cards are 16# in length (UK) Maestro can be up to 19 so length checks become a PITA.

Answer (score 5):

Here's [Complete C# or VB code for all kinds of CC related things](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20271/Ultimate-NET-Credit-Card-Utility-Class) on codeproject.

- IsValidNumber
- GetCardTypeFromNumber
- GetCardTestNumber
- PassesLuhnTest

This article has been up for a couple years with no negative comments.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_number) contains a list of most card prefixes. Some cards are missing from the link you posted. It also appears that the link you provided is valid.

One reason to ask for the card type is for extra validation, compare what the user provided against the number.

Answer (score 4):

This is the php version of same algorithm mentioned in 1st post

```
<?php
function CreditCardType($CardNo)
{
/*
'*CARD TYPES            *PREFIX           *WIDTH
'American Express       34, 37            15
'Diners Club            300 to 305, 36    14
'Carte Blanche          38                14
'Discover               6011              16
'EnRoute                2014, 2149        15
'JCB                    3                 16
'JCB                    2131, 1800        15
'Master Card            51 to 55          16
'Visa                   4                 13, 16
*/    
//Just in case nothing is found
$CreditCardType = "Unknown";

//Remove all spaces and dashes from the passed string
$CardNo = str_replace("-", "",str_replace(" ", "",$CardNo));

//Check that the minimum length of the string isn't less
//than fourteen characters and -is- numeric
If(strlen($CardNo) < 14 || !is_numeric($CardNo))
    return false;

//Check the first two digits first
switch(substr($CardNo,0, 2))
{
    Case 34: Case 37:
        $CreditCardType = "American Express";
        break;
    Case 36:
        $CreditCardType = "Diners Club";
        break;
    Case 38:
        $CreditCardType = "Carte Blanche";
        break;
    Case 51: Case 52: Case 53: Case 54: Case 55:
        $CreditCardType = "Master Card";
        break;
}

//None of the above - so check the
if($CreditCardType == "Unknown")
{
    //first four digits collectively
    switch(substr($CardNo,0, 4))
    {
        Case 2014:Case 2149:
            $CreditCardType = "EnRoute";
            break;
        Case 2131:Case  1800:
            $CreditCardType = "JCB";
            break;
        Case 6011:
            $CreditCardType = "Discover";
            break;
    }
}

//None of the above - so check the
if($CreditCardType == "Unknown")
{
    //first three digits collectively
    if(substr($CardNo,0, 3) >= 300 && substr($CardNo,0, 3) <= 305)
    {
        $CreditCardType = "American Diners Club";
    }
}

//None of the above -
if($CreditCardType == "Unknown")
{
    //So simply check the first digit
    switch(substr($CardNo,0, 1))
    {
        Case 3:
            $CreditCardType = "JCB";
            break;
        Case 4:
            $CreditCardType = "Visa";
            break;
    }
}

return $CreditCardType;
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you linked has an **incomplete BIN/range list** for Discover, omits Diner's club (which now belongs to Discover anyway), lists card types that no longer exist and should be folded into other types (enRoute, Carte Blanche), and ignores the increasingly-important Maestro International cart type.

As @Alex confirmed, it's possible to determine the card type from the BIN number, and numerous companies do it but doing so consistently and correctly is not trivial: card brands constantly change, and keeping track of things becomes more complicated as you try to handle regional debit cards (Laser in Ireland, Maestro in Europe, etc) - I have not found a free and maintained (correct) piece of code or algorithm for this anywhere.

As @MitMaro poined out, [Wikipedia contains a high-level list of card identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_number), and also [a more-specific list of BIN numbers and ranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Issuer_Identification_Numbers#BIN_Ranges), which is a good start, and as gbjbaanb commented, [Barclays has a publically-published list](http://www.barclaycard.co.uk/business/documents/pdfs/bin_rules.pdf) (but it does not seem to include Discover for some reason - presumably they don't process on the Discover network?)

Trivial as it may seem, a correct card-identification algorithm/method/function takes work to maintain, so unless your detection routine is non-critical/informational (eg @Simon_Weaver's suggestion), OR you're going to put in the work to keep it current, I would recommend that you skip the automatic detection.

Answer (score 3):

Stripe has provided this fantastic **javascript** library for card scheme detection. Let me add few code snippets and show you how to use it.

Firstly Include it to your web page as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.payment/1.2.3/jquery.payment.js " ></script>
```

Secondly use the function cardType for detecting the card scheme.

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
            var type = $.payment.cardType("4242 4242 4242 4242"); //test card number
            console.log(type);                                   
});
```

Here are the reference links for more examples and demos.

1. [Stripe blog for jquery.payment.js](https://stripe.com/blog/jquery-payment)
2. [Github repository](https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick a dirty way to determine the card type automatically and show it to the user while they're typing.

That means 
a) the user doesnt have to pick it and 
b) they wont waste time looking for a dropdown that doesnt exist.

Very simple jQuery version for Amex, Visa and Mastercard.
if you need other card types you can take the

```
 $('[id$=CreditCardNumber]').assertOne().keyup(function(){

        // rules taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_number#cite_note-GenCardFeatures-0
        var value = $(this).val();

        $('#ccCardType').removeClass("unknown");
        if ((/^4/).test(value)) {
            $('#ccCardType').html("Visa");
            return;
        }
        if ((/^5[1-5]/).test(value)) {
           $('#ccCardType').html("Mastercard");
           return;
        }
        if ((/^3[47]/).test(value)) {
           $('#ccCardType').html("Mastercard");
           return;
        }
        $('#ccCardType').html("Enter card number above");
        $('#ccCardType').addClass("unknown");
     });
```

This is the jQuery to accompany this (ASP.NET MVC):

```
  Card number: <%= Html.TextBox("PaymentDetails.CreditCardDetails.CreditCardNumber")%>
  Card Type: <span id="ccCardType" class="unknown">Enter card number above</span>
```

I have a css rule for `.unknown` to display grayed out text.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation in Python should work for AmEx, Discover, Master Card, Visa:

```
def cardType(number):
    number = str(number)
    cardtype = "Invalid"
    if len(number) == 15:
        if number[:2] == "34" or number[:2] == "37":
            cardtype = "American Express"
    if len(number) == 13:
        if number[:1] == "4":
            cardtype = "Visa"
    if len(number) == 16:
        if number[:4] == "6011":
            cardtype = "Discover"
        if int(number[:2]) >= 51 and int(number[:2]) <= 55:
            cardtype = "Master Card"
        if number[:1] == "4":
            cardtype = "Visa"
    return cardtype
```

Comment: Credit cards arent too bad as they follow a set of rules; we have Maestro cards which cause all the issues as they use the same start codes as Credit Card producers and have over 16digits.

Answer (score 1):

If all the credit cards that you accept have the same properties then just let the user enter the card number and other properties (expiry date, CVV, etc). However, some card types require different fields to be entered (e.g. start date or issue number for UK Maestro cards). In those cases, you either have to have all fields, thereby confusing the user, or some Javascript to hide/show the relevant fields, again making the user experience a bit weird (fields disappearing/appearing, as they enter the credit card number). In those cases, I recommend asking for the card type first.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have no problem with picking the card type first. But there are two aspects of credit card number entry that are problematic in my view.

The worst is the inability to enter spaces between groups of numbers. Including the spaces printed on the physical cards would make the digits vastly easier for the user to scan to verify they've entered the information correctly. Every time I encounter this ubiquitous deficiency I feel like I'm being propelled backwards into a stone age when user input couldn't be filtered to remove unnecessary characters.

The second is the need when placing a phone order to listen to the vendor repeat the card number back to you. All the credit card recipient actually needs is a UI that gives them access to the check digit scheme which verifies that a cc number is valid. According to that algorithm the first 15 (or however many) digits calculate the last digit - and is virtually impossible to "fool." For a fat fingered number to "pass" requires at least two mutually canceling errors among the 15 digits. Unless the algorithm suffers from the defect of being dis-proportionally fooled by transposing adjacent numbers (a common entry error) which I doubt, I except it is more reliable than any human double check.

Answer (score 0):

https://binlist.net/ offers a free API. You only need to enter the first 6 or 8 digits of the card number - i.e. the Issuer Identification Numbers (IIN), previously known as Bank Identification Number (BIN).

`curl -H "Accept-Version: 3" "https://lookup.binlist.net/45717360"`

- NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/binlookup
- Source: https://github.com/paylike/binlookup

(cross-posted from a more specific question: [How tell the difference between a Debit Card and a Credit Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479363/how-tell-the-difference-between-a-debit-card-and-a-credit-card) )