# How to get "credit" or "debit" type of Authorize.net transaction

Tags: php, api, authorize.net

Authorize.net API returns quite a lot for a `getTransactionDetails` call, but there is no indication, whether the transaction is of CREDIT or DEBIT type. I can see the transaction amount, but seems like it's always positive.

I'd like to get DEBIT/CREDIT flag or any other advice on how to get it.

Here is an example of `getTransactionDetails` call:

```
[messages] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [resultCode] => Ok
    [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [code] => I00001
            [text] => Successful.
        )

)

[transaction] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [transId] => 123456789
    [submitTimeUTC] => 2015-07-22T10:36:54.413Z
    [submitTimeLocal] => 2015-07-22T09:36:54.413
    [transactionType] => authCaptureTransaction
    [transactionStatus] => settledSuccessfully
    [responseCode] => 1
    [responseReasonCode] => 1
    [responseReasonDescription] => Approval
    [authCode] => 143500
    [AVSResponse] => Y
    [batch] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [batchId] => 330390000
            [settlementTimeUTC] => 2015-07-23T00:45:46.757Z
            [settlementTimeLocal] => 2015-07-22T12:45:46.757
            [settlementState] => settledSuccessfully
        )

    [order] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [invoiceNumber] => 0002
        )

    [authAmount] => 1.39
    [settleAmount] => 1.39
    [taxExempt] => false
    [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [cardNumber] => XXXX2211
                    [expirationDate] => XXXX
                    [cardType] => Visa
                )

        )

    [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [firstName] => John
            [lastName] => Doe
            [company] => Food Ind., LLC
            [address] => 221b Baker Street
            [city] => New York
            [state] => New York
            [zip] => 10004
            [country] => USA
        )

    [shipTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [firstName] => John
            [lastName] => Doe
            [company] => Food Ind., LLC
            [address] => 221b Baker Street
            [city] => New York
            [state] => New York
            [zip] => 10004
            [country] => USA
        )

    [recurringBilling] => false
    [product] => Card Not Present
    [marketType] => eCommerce
)
```

Comment: I don't think they know it themselves. There is no way of knowing the type based on the information provided by the user and I'm guessing the bank does not disclose this information either. Keep in mind that banks issue debit cards that work like credit cards (you can spend more than you have). So that's a credit card too. Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479363/how-tell-the-difference-between-a-debit-card-and-a-credit-card

Comment: I think he meant not the type of the card, but the type of transaction, which can be either debit or credit (+ or -) always, no matter what card type one has.

Comment: Check this
http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/
or 
http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/#hosted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to Authorize.net support, and they answered next:

*Whenever a charge is for money being deposited into your account, its status should be "Settled Successfully." For charges where money is being removed from your bank account, the status will read "Refund" in the transaction status.*

So, if transaction status is "settled" - it's transaction where moneys come on account. If status is "refund" -  it's transaction where moneys go from account.

Answer (score 1):

It's *always* credit because Authorize.Net does *not* process PIN-based debit cards. PIN-based debit cards go through an entirely different system outside of the credit card processing world. Bank cards with the Visa or MasterCard logo that are considered credit cards when used without a PIN number and debit cards when they do. But when used as a credit card they are not special in any way and will not be noted just like business cards and rewards cards are not.