# Jquery find credit card type

Tags: jquery

I found this simple function to return the 4 most common credit card types.

Being new to jQuery, what jQuery plugin can I use to display the credit card type as a user types in a credit card number in a input field?

```
 function creditCardTypeFromNumber(num) {
   // first, sanitize the number by removing all non-digit characters.
   num = num.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
   // now test the number against some regexes to figure out the card type.
   if (num.match(/^5[1-5]\d{14}$/)) {
     return 'MasterCard';
   } else if (num.match(/^4\d{15}/) || num.match(/^4\d{12}/)) {
     return 'Visa';
   } else if (num.match(/^3[47]\d{13}/)) {
     return 'AmEx';
   } else if (num.match(/^6011\d{12}/)) {
     return 'Discover';
   }
   return 'UNKNOWN';
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#someTextBox').change(function() {
    $('#someOutput').text(creditCardTypeFromNumber($(this).val()));
});
```

This will output into some element with `id="someOutput"` the result of the text box which fires when the user changes the text in the element `id="someTextBox"`.

Comment: `change()` will not get fired until text input loses focus. Use keyup() instead for validation as you type

Comment: I know is kinda old, but I was looking for something just like this. Just wanted to note, @Daniel A. White You need an extra ) at the end of line 2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ihwy.com/labs/jquery-validate-credit-card-extension.aspx

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/creditcard

Plugins by default may not have the card validation as you type. To have realtime validation, you can bind a simple [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) on the input field so validation is done after each key stroke.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Credit Card Type Detector Plugin https://github.com/christianreed/Credit-Card-Type-Detector

Answer (score 0):

Also, FYI, the answer on [this thread (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number) has some regex for other card types, as well as an awesome explanation of credit card numbers.

Here's a function that only fires after they entered at least 6 digits (the ones used to recognize card type):

```
$('#CardNumber').keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val().length >= 6){
       cardType = creditCardTypeFromNumber($(this).val());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a free BIN API service like https://tripayments.com/bins/ .  Submit the first 6 and it will give the "DetailCardProduct" which is VISA, Mastercard,etc