# Credit Card validation in Zend Framework

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you detect Credit card type based on number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number)

So I know I can use Zend_Validate to Validate a Credit Card number against a list of "accepted" credit card types.

I was wondering if there is a similar feature / way to determine what type of credit card it is based on credit card number?