# Regular Expression for Credit card information should not allow characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regular expression `^4[0-9]{15}$` to check credit card information starting with `4` for VISA and that are 16 digits long.

This expression accepts credit card numbers like `4141414141414141aa` which is wrong, as it accepts alpha-characters in the end of a valid credit card number.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The regex by itself looks fine. Can you show how you are using this in your code?

Comment: What you are describing is very much impossible. That regex you have should not, by any means, allow anything after a total of 16 numbers.

Comment: In what programming language, or what regex package?

Comment: I am using Javascript .. Not sure why I am able to enter these values

Comment: Curious...  Does the *input field* allow you to enter the non-digit characters, or is the value with non-digit characters passing the *validation check*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect Credit card type based on number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number)

Comment: You should probably allow spaces in the credit card input. Otherwise you are going to annoy at lot of people (and it is bad UX).

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in Java, anchors are not `^` and `$`, but `\A` and `\z`, so your regex would be

```
"\\A4[0-9]{15}\\z"
```

or

```
"\\A4\\d{15}\\z"
```

---

In Javascript the anchors should indeed be `^` and `$` making the regular expression:

```
/^4\d{15}$/
```

Tested in my Firebug Javascript console:

```
>>> var val1='4141414141414141';
>>> var val2='4141414141414141aa';
>>> /^4\d{15}$/.test(val1);
true
>>> /^4\d{15}$/.test(val2);
false
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am using Javascript to check the regex and html is the front end where user inputs data.  Since you  all have validated that this expression is right, i should probably check other parts of my code for errors. Many Thanks!

Comment: @user997509 - maybe you could include some code to show exactly when and how you're checking for a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\b` to match the start and end of a word in JavaScript. So it can be:

```
if (/\b4\d{12}(?:\d{3})?\b/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match

} else {
    // No match

}
```

according to http://tools.twainscanning.com/getmyregex