# Should I collect and store the type of credit card (e.g. Visa) or determine it via the number?

Tags: regex, validation, credit-card

I am writing code for entering credit cards into a database. I am aware there are regular expressions that can be used to determine type of card (Visa, MasterCard, etc). For instance, Visa's regex is `/^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/`. I only deal with Visa, MasterCard, Discover Card, and American Express, with no other cards being supported.

My question is: Should I collect the card type from the user and store it in the database, or derive the card type from the card number, and *not* store it in the database? In other words, are there any cases where, for instance, a Visa card will not match the regex, but still be a Visa card?

This is not about Luhn checking, it's about regular expressions for determining card type.

Comment: For what it's worth, systems that I've seen ask the user and store it. This is not the thing you want to guess wrong to save a few bytes.

Comment: You should only derive card type from card number. There is no info from any other check box tick that can give you info. Monitor card numbers and modify your regex in a timely manner. I don't think it will change much. However, you could loosen your regex up a little to catch typo's.

Comment: Referring to an excellent answer to related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number it's good to prompt for and save the issuer, rather than determining the issuer from REGEX pattern.

Comment: Thanks, all. I'm not concerned with saving space, but I want to avoid people entering a Visa card and then selecting MasterCard. This has happened quite a lot in the past because some older customers seem to think everything is a MasterCard.

Comment: Off topic because it is about weather credit card numbers are systematic or not in regard to card type. Not a programming problem.

Comment: @NielsCastle You just want *everything* to be offtopic, don't you? Saves actually trying to answer a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there any cases where, for instance, a Visa card will not match
>   the regex, but still be a Visa card?

Yes, that Visa expression limits to 13 *or* 16 digits when in reality Visa can range from 13 thru 19 digits, albeit that 16 is by far the most common.

> Should I collect the card type from the user

This is discussed in depth here: [Why do credit card forms ask for Visa, MasterCard, etc.?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51346/why-do-credit-card-forms-ask-for-visa-mastercard-etc)

As you comment you are experiencing problems with incorrect user input, I would simply not ask them what they are using and use a set of simple prefix and length regular expressions to identity the type of the card.  You can then store this value in your database to save deriving it again the the future for query purposes).