# Identifier not recognised

Tags: c, identifier

I've been trying to put together a program that can recognise credit card numbers from different companies- I've been building it piecemeal, and I've managed to get almost every section to work. All the code seems to work up until the final section where I try to make sure that the input is between certain numbers to decide which company a card belongs to. The error I receive is on the line `if (f == 0) && (number > 339999999999999) && (number < 380000000000000)`, apparently it expects an identifier for "number" - I thought the fact that I had declared it at the very top would circumvent this, but apparently not.

```
long long number;

int main(void)
{
    long long i = 0;
    long long b;
    long long m = 10;
    long long n = 1;
    number = get_long_long("Number?\n");
    do
    {
        long long a = number % m;
        b = number - a;
        long long c = b % (m * 10);
        long long d = c / m;
        long long e = d *2;
        if (e < 9)
        {
            i = i + e;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + (e - 10 + 1);
        }
        
        {
            m = m * 100;
        }
    }
    while (b > 0);
    do
    {
        long long a = number % n;
        b = number - a;
        long long c = b % (n * 10);
        long long d = c / n;
        long long e = d *2;
        if (e < 9)
        {
            i = i + e;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + (e - 10 + 1);
        }
        
        {
            n = n * 100;
        }
    }
    while (b > 0);
    int f = i % 10;
    if (f == 0) && (number > 339999999999999) && (number < 380000000000000)
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else
    if (f == 0) && (number > 1099999999999999) && (number < 5600000000000000)
    {
        printf("Mastercard\n");
    }
    else
    if (f == 0) && ((number > 3999999999999999) && (number < 5000000000000000) || (number > 3999999999999) && (number < 5000000000000))
    {
        printf("Visa\n");
    }
    else
    {
    printf("invalid\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing brackets around the whole `if` condition `((f == 0) && (number > 339999999999999) && (number < 380000000000000))`

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of trouble by reading the number as a string.

Comment: @kaylum I modified this as you suggested- it now points to the OR operator, with the error: "expected expression".

Comment: @user3386109 do you mean I should replace all instances of "long long" with "string"?

Comment: As far as I know, credit cards numbers aren't really numbers, they're strings of digits. And they're not necessarily 16 in length either, so a numeric range test is not the correct way to do this. The first 6 or 8 digits denote the IIN and that tells you the issuer. Amex, for example, is 34xxxx or 37xxxx. Specifically, Amex does not begin 35 or 36, which your algorithm will incorrectly identify as Amex. Also, read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number

Comment: That's the first step. Search for `[c] Luhn` for examples.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks, I'll try to make some adjustments.

Comment: @BlueKhakis Can't tell you what the problem is without seeing the **exact** modification you did.

Comment: @kaylum Ah I just put a bracket in the wrong place, fixed, thanks.