# Is there a way to detect the type of card i.e Debit or Credit

Tags: types, credit-card, luhn, card

I need to detect the card type: Debit or Credit when the customer is on website's checkout page.

I am using the library i.e https://github.com/braintree/credit-card-type already to determine the card **brand** i.e Visa,Amex,Mastercard etc. But these don't provide the card **type** info. Is this possible at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you detect Credit card type based on number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number)

Comment: I did go through the post but i believe the accepted answer focussed more on determining the card brands i.e Visa, Amex, MAstercard, JCB etc and not the actual card type info i.e Debit or Credit

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You need to get a list of BIN (**B**ank **I**dentification **N**umbers) which correlate to card type (debit or credit). You then can compare the BIN number, which is the first 4-9 numbers of the card, to that list which will tell you the card type.

Processors like Worldpay and Card Connect make lists like this available. I am unsure if there is a cost or not. I found [this free one](https://www.bindb.com/bin-list.html) but you'll need to massage it a bit to consume it programmatically. [This API](https://binlist.net/) also claims to be free.

Comment: Thanks. So we can only compare  against a database of BINs provided by Banks to determine if its Debit or Credit. 

Is it safe to assume that we cannot use some kind of pattern matching or regex to deduce from card numbers (say first 6 digits) itself that its a debit or credit like we can do to determine card brands i,e Visa, mastercard?

Comment: Correct for card type (credit, debit). The type of card is not "encoded" or otherwise a factor in creating card numbers. Card brands (Visa, MasterCard) can be determined by the numbers, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another api solution at rapidapi [Bank Card Bin Num Check](https://rapidapi.com/blackbunny/api/bank-card-bin-num-check) there are 250K+ issued card type.

Just one GET request with cards first 6 number. and see result

```
{ "bin_number": 535177, "bank": "Finansbank A.S.", "scheme": "MASTERCARD", "type": "Debit", "country": "Turkey" }
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
// Function to detect card company based on the card number's first digits
function detectCardCompany(cardNumber) {
  // Remove non-digit characters from the card number
  const cleanedCardNumber = cardNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');

  // Determine the card company based on the first digits
  const firstDigits = cleanedCardNumber.slice(0, 6); // Consider the first 6 digits

  switch (true) {
    case /^4/.test(firstDigits):
      return require(`../../assets/social/visa.png`);
    case /^5[1-5]/.test(firstDigits):
      return require(`../../assets/social/master.png`);
    case /^3[47]/.test(firstDigits):
      return require(`../../assets/social/american.png`);
    case /^6/.test(firstDigits):
      return require(`../../assets/social/discover.png`);
    case /^30[0-5]|^36|^38|^39/.test(firstDigits):
      return require(`../../assets/social/master.png`);
    case /^35(2[89]|[3-8][0-9])/.test(firstDigits):
      return require(`../../assets/social/jcb.png`);
    case /^62/.test(firstDigits):
      return require(`../../assets/social/union.png`);
    default:
      return require(`../../assets/social/visa.png`);
  }
}
```

`

Comment: How does this code ever end up in `union` branch?