# Will there be changes to credit card type detection with the new 8-digit BIN/IIN?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, e-commerce, credit-card

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number) has some answers for how to calculate credit card issuer based on the 6-digit BIN/IIN.

> Visa: ^4[0-9]{6,}$ Visa card numbers start with a 4.
>
> MasterCard: ^5[1-5][0-9]{5,}|222[1-9][0-9]{3,}|22[3-9][0-9]{4,}|2[3-6][0-9]{5,}|27[01][0-9]{4,}|2720[0-9]{3,}$ Before 2016, MasterCard numbers start with the numbers 51 through 55, but this will only detect MasterCard credit cards; there are other cards issued using the MasterCard system that do not fall into this IIN range. In 2016, they will add numbers in the range (222100-272099).
>
> American Express: ^3[47][0-9]{5,}$ American Express card numbers start with 34 or 37.
>
> Diners Club: ^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{4,}$ Diners Club card numbers begin with 300 through 305, 36 or 38. There are Diners Club cards that begin with 5 and have 16 digits. These are a joint venture between Diners Club and MasterCard and should be processed like a MasterCard.
>
> Discover: ^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3,}$ Discover card numbers begin with 6011 or 65.
>
> JCB: ^(?:2131|1800|35[0-9]{3})[0-9]{3,}$ JCB cards begin with 2131, 1800 or 35.

Now that Visa and Mastercard will be using 8-digit BINs, will any changes be required? Visa has made [this FAQ doc](https://usa.visa.com/dam/VCOM/global/partner-with-us/documents/visa.com-numerics-faq.pdf) available, but it doesn't seem to indicate whether there will be any changes.

Comment: The increase in bin length 6 to 8 would primarily be to accommodate more bins from the banks, it don't seem to induce any other change

Answer (score 0):

The US Payments Forum (https://www.uspaymentsforum.org/) has been working on a white paper describing the impacts of these new 8-digit BINs but I believe it has not yet been published.

Mastercard has also published a brief about it: https://www.mastercard.com/content/dam/public/mastercardcom/globalrisk/pdf/8-Digit%20BIN%20Expansion%20and%20PCI%20Standards%20-%20FINAL%20(10-20-2021).pdf

If you are on the acquiring side, I don't think the 8-digit BINs will cause a lot of changes. Issuers/Issuer Processors who want to adopt them will have more work (there's probably a lot of hardcoded/implicit lengths of 6 in codes handling BINs or PANs)